# R replace element in data frame

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

This is the code to implement my data frame:

```
breast <- read.table("breastdata.txt", header=T, sep=" ", fill=TRUE)
```

Now I want like to replace the first column, that contains factor M and B, to the factor -1 and +1. 
So when it is "M" then I would replace it by +1.
I've got the next code but it doesn't work:

```
for(i in 1:569)      
{   
  if(breast[i,1]=="M")  
  {   
    breast[i,1] <- as.factor(-1)   
   }   
  else{   
    breast[i,1] <- as.factor(1)   
  }   
}
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `levels(breast[,1]) == c("B", "M")`, just call:

```
levels(breast[,1]) <- c("1", "-1")
```

This will only change the factor's labels, without changing its internal representation. Thus, it is a very fast operation.

Answer (score 2):

```
breast$first_column[breast$first_column=="B"] <- "1"
breast$first_column[breast$first_column=="M"] <- "-1"
```

Comment: I don't think this would work if the `first_column` were a `factor` and `"1"` were not a defined factor level of it.